# Grayed out push and pull on Rstudio

Tags: r, git, rstudio

I want my project in Rstudio to connect to a repository. However, the push and pull options are grayed out, which leads me to believe I am not connected.

Under tools -> project options -> Git/SVN,  I see that I am using Git as the version control system, but the Origin box is grayed out, so I cannot enter the URL that would connect to the repo.

Any ideas what is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/git.html#github-init). Use the shell to run `git remote add origin [your_repo.git]`

Comment: Thanks Axeman, but it returns "fatal: remote origin already exists"

Comment: To make it weirder, when I run "git status" it tells me all the files I need are in there

Comment: Try pushing from the shell. It will probably give you an error and some info on how to fix it